# Can't add domain users to local groups on a server

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I'm trying to add a user to a local group on one of my servers. I keep getting the following error once I've selected the user I want to add:

> Windows cannot process the object with the name 'Domain Account' because of the following error:
>   The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.

I'm also seeing a lot of EventID 1053 errors which give pretty much the same error and then say Group Policy processing aborted.

The strange thing is that I'm logging in to this server with my domain account, the domain controller is running fine, and I can even get a listing of domain accounts to add to the group. It only fails once I select which user I want to add from the list. Any ideas as to what might be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the server in question isn't a domain controller, in which case, have you checked its DNS settings?

They should be configured to use the same DNS server that your AD is using.

Can you perform an nslookup on your domain name from the server?

For example (assuming your DNS domain name is example.local)

```
h:\> nslookup example.local
Server dc1.example.local
Addresss: 1.2.3.4

Name:    example.local
Addresses:  1.2.3.4, 1.2.3.5, 1.2.3.6
```

It's worth checking, as in my experience, this type of error usually is down to DNS configuration being wrong somewhere along the line.

Comment: I switched my primary DNS to my domain controller. We have a national DNS we have to use and every once in a while it seems to become the primary DNS on some of our servers. Looks like this error was just a product of our crazy environment =/. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're having the group policy processing as well, it's a safe bet that some kind of connectivity to the domain controller is broken.  Name resolution is the first place I'd look; make sure the domain's netbios name, the first block of the DNS name (which should match the netbios, unless your domain's disjointed), and the FQDN are all resolving to the DC.

Then, since group policy's not working right, make sure you're able to get to the sysvol share via the domain's FQDN (`\\\\domain.com\\sysvol`).

From there, try to connect via dsa.msc to the global catalog and make sure that's working.

Comment: You might also look on the DC to see if it is reporting a relationship problem with your member server.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and it turned out one of my DCs was on the incorrect time after being in saved state.

I just fixed it to get time properly and the error disappeared